# Как проверить TextBox'ы на пустоту исключая некоторые?

Tags: c#

У меня на форме есть пару Текстбоксов. Как Я могу проверить их на пустоту, исключая 1-2 текстбокса?

Вариант с использованием:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text)) || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text)))
```

Не подходит))

Есть вариант:

```
foreach (Control c in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
  {
    c.Text = "";
  }
}
```

Но как мне обойти некоторые текстбоксы?

Comment: например по имени или текста внутри

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (Control c in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
  if (c != некоторый_textbox && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
  {
    c.Text = "";
  }
}
```

или

```
List<TextBox> toSkip = new List<TextBox>() { textBox1, textBox2 };
...
foreach (Control c in Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Except(toSkip))
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
  {
    c.Text = "";
  }
}
```